# Как проверить права доступа к файлам на Nginx?

Tags: nginx, безопасность, jwt

Пишу небольшой под проект, для себя. Приложение должно будет раздавать картинки, проверяя права доступа к ним.
По стеку Nginx + Java + Mysql.
Пользователь переходит по url
На сервере Nginx, перенаправляет запрос на java приложение, там проверяется например referer, токен или куки. И выдается вердикт можно дать доступ или нет.
Nginx получив ответ отдает запрошенную картину или 404.

Можно ли настроить Nginx, так чтобы он на основании ответа с порта отдавал нужный контент?

Comment: https://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_auth_request_module.html

Comment: Огромное спасибо. Я смотрел доку, видел варианты с .htaccess и тд. Но модули не заметил